# Show equivalence using venn diagram, subset argument, membership table

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that A \ (B ∩ C) = (A \ B) U (A \ C)

Using:

a) Venn diagram

b) Subset argument

c) Membership table

I can do the venn diagram, you just draw the shapes and show that the end shape for both are the same correct? I am stuck on the subset argument and the membership table though. Thanks.

Prove:

Let x ∈ A \ (B n C)

Therefore x ∈ A v (x ∈ B ^ x ∈ B)  <--- Last 2 x's have dashes above them

Therefore X ∈ (A \ B) U (A \ C)

Comment: Do you know what a membership table is? If so, how far did you get?

Comment: No, it looks like a truth table though, so i assume you do it the same way as one?

Comment: Also, with b it seems there is literally only one step?

Comment: There are at least two steps in $b$ since you need to prove one set is a subset of the other and the other way around.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, it's just to tell you that  there's an easier way to prove it:$A\backslash (B\cap C)=A\cap (\bar{B}\cup \bar{C})=(A\cap\bar{B})\cup (A\cap\bar{C})=(A\backslash B)\cup (A\backslash C)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The membership table should look like this:

$$\begin{array}{ccc|cc}A & B & C & A\setminus(B\cap C) & (A\setminus B)\cup (A\setminus C)\\\hline
1&1&1&*&*\\
1&1&0&*&*\\
1&0&1&*&*\\
1&0&0&*&*\\
0&1&1&*&*\\
0&1&0&*&*\\
0&0&1&*&*\\
0&0&0&*&*\\
\end{array}$$

Now just fill in the blanks and see if they match up.

The subset argument looks like:

1. Let $x\in A\setminus(B\cap C)$. Then, something something somethig, and therefore, $x\in (A\setminus B)\cup (A\setminus C)$
2. Let $x\in (A\setminus B)\cup (A\setminus C)$. This means that... and therefore, $x\in A\setminus(B\cap C)$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27599/discussion-on-answer-by-5xum-show-equivalence-using-venn-diagram-subset-argumen).

Comment: @DanielFischer I agree comments are not for extended discussion, but I find the lack of MathJax in the comments... disturbing.

Comment: Fortunately, there's [robjohn's ChatJax bookmarklet](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html) to render MathJax in chat. I had the impression that your exchange was now finished, and moved it to remove the clutter from the page, since I expect for most people it won't be very interesting.